# CSS Transition not firing after transition end

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having some problems with firing transitions through jQuery.
After the first transition completes, I want the other div to fade in, but the opacity do not executes de transition. It goes straight to `opacity: 1;`.
I was able to work around with `setTimeout`, but I was wondering if there's a problem in my code or something

```js
var endTransition = "transitionend";

$('#test').click(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity', '0').one(endTransition, function() {
    $('#test').css('display', 'none');
    $('#test2').css('display', 'inline-block').css('opacity', '1');
  });
});

$('#test2').click(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity', '0').one(endTransition, function() {
    $('#test2').css('display', 'none');
    $('#test').css('display', 'inline-block').css('opacity', '1');
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

#test2 {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>
```

Comment: it seems your problem is you have `.css('display','inline-block')` before you call `.css('opacity','1')`. That's the reason your element is showing up immediately because of css `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple and elegant solution:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(function() {
    $('div').not(this).fadeIn().css("display","inline-block");
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#test2 {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='test2'></div>
```

Comment: Hi. First, thanks for the help. So, I need the second div to be `display: inline-block;`, that's the big problem here for me. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: btw, I trying to make the animations be css transitions. I'm building an web app, so I'm trying to make as smooth animations as possible, and I notice that CSS transitions are smoother than jQuery animation.

Comment: Making divs `inline-block` when they are shown is an easy fix - I added it to the above snippet. As for the CSS transitions - `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are CSS opacity transitions with `display:none` in the end, but controlled via JavaScript through jQuery. Using ready functions of jQuery makes your code shorter and neater, that's all jQuery does. If you don't use jQuery, you'll have to write your own functions to control the opacity, and the question is - is it going to be faster, safer, more cross-browser-compatible than jQuery? I say stick to tried and tested JS (and in this case, jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var endTransition = "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend";

$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity',0).off().one(endTransition, function(e) {
        // your callback
    });
});
```

- use more browser-specific event names for cross-browser compatibility.
- use `off()` to remove all former event binds.
- **EDIT:** it seems your problem is you have `.css('display','inline-block')` before you call `.css('opacity','1')`. That's the reason your element is showing up immediately because of css `display: inline-block`.